# Get unflattened filtered Multidimensional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, filter

I am able to filter the elements of matrix W to elements that satisfy the conditional statement `=>` keep elements in each inner matrix that is below the median value. The elements of the median array are the median values for each inner array.

```js
const W = [[45, 60, 15, 35],[45, 55, 75],[12, 34, 80, 65, 90]
];
const median = [ 40, 55, 65 ];
const Wmin = [];
for (let j = 0; j < W.length; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < W[j].length; k++) {
        if (W[j][k] < median[j]) {
            Wmin.push(W[j][k]);
        }
    }
}


console.log(Wmin)
```

I used a for-loop, but the resulting Wmin array is flattened. My goal is to be able to filter W and still get unflattened 2D array.

I am getting `Wmin = [ 15, 35, 45, 12, 34 ]`, but the expected array should be `Wmin = [ [15, 35], [45], [12, 34] ]`

Comment: How do you determine the results using `[ 40, 55, 65 ];`?

Comment: I used mathjs library to the get the median of each inner matrix, here is the code                   
`const median = [];
for (let j = 0; j < W.length; j++) {
    median[j] = math.median(W[j]);
}`

Comment: Use a let for wmin if you expect to change it later. Small suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const W = [[45, 60, 15, 35],[45, 55, 75],[12, 34, 80, 65, 90]];
const median = [ 40, 55, 65 ];

const op = W.map(( inp, index) => inp.filter(e => e < median[index]))

console.log(op)
```

> Why my code is not working

You're pushing values directly into array inside inner  for loop, you need to create a temporary array and push value in it in inner loop and push the temporary to `Wmin` in outer loop

```js
const W = [[45, 60, 15, 35],[45, 55, 75],[12, 34, 80, 65, 90]];
const median = [ 40, 55, 65 ];
const Wmin = [];
   for (let j = 0; j < W.length; j++) {
     let temp = []
      for (let k = 0; k < W[j].length; k++) {
         if (W[j][k] < median[j]) {
            temp.push(W[j][k]);
         }
     }
  Wmin.push(temp)
}

console.log(Wmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to solve this problem could be making a copy of the original array with [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and then iterate over the elements of this copy deleting the numbers that don't meet the condition (i.e are greater or equal to the median) with [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```js
const W = [[45, 60, 15, 35],[45, 55, 75],[12, 34, 80, 65, 90]];
const median = [40, 55, 65];

// Clone the original array.

let Wmin = W.slice();

// Delete elements from the cloned array.

for (let j = 0; j < Wmin.length; j++)
{
    for (let k = 0; k < Wmin[j].length; k++)
    {
        if (Wmin[j][k] >= median[j])
        {
            Wmin[j].splice(k, 1);
            --k;
        }
    }
}

console.log(Wmin);
```

Or, if you like, you can approach this with [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) too:

```js
const W = [[45, 60, 15, 35],[45, 55, 75],[12, 34, 80, 65, 90]];
const median = [40, 55, 65];

let Wmin = W.reduce(
    (acc, arr, i) => (acc.push(arr.filter(x => x < median[i])) && acc),
    []
);

console.log(Wmin);
```